# RemoteViews addView function returns errors on AppWidget

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I'm trying to create a AppWidget that displays a number of items (which can change). I'd like to generate TextViews dynamically, I assume I do this by using:

```
RemoteViews updateViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.id.widgetmain);
RemoteViews newView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.id.widgetitem);

updateViews.addView(0, newView);
```

But this returns a `Problem loading widget` error. The widgetitem.xml is just a TextView within a LinearLayout. The widgetmain.xml is two TextViews within a LinearLayout.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

> updateViews.addView(**0**, newView);

You should specify correct viewId rather than 0 as the parent of your widgetitem. For your exmaple, you can probably add an empty container under widgetmain for this purpose.

Comment: I'd like to add that this id should be Id of view under which you want to add your item.